# How to test for block change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was trying to create a way so when someone stands on an iron pressure plate, it says hello to them in chat.

The command is:

Command block 1:

```
testfor -87.643 65 -67.535 heavy_weighted_pressure_plate
```

Command block 2:

```
say Welcome
```

But when I stood on the pressure plate nothing happened

It says:

> [18:16:21] Entity '-87.442' cannot be found

Comment: This might help you a little bit: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/166697/how-to-make-a-command-block-say-something-only-once-in-minecraft

Answer (score 2):

`/testfor` is for entities only. If you want to check a block instead, use `/testforblock`.

It looks like you've copied the coordinates from your exact feet position. These may not end up rounding correctly to a block position; I'd recommend using the `Looking At` values instead:

[image: Looking at coordinates]

The following command will test for a heavy weighted pressure plate at `(-88,65,-68)`, regardless of its power level:

```
/testforblock -88 65 -68 heavy_weighted_pressure_plate
```

You can then test for a specific power level with blockstates like this:

```
/testforblock -88 65 -68 heavy_weighted_pressure_plate power=1
```

Comment: I tried what you said but it says that the power=0 instead of 1

Comment: @theExtinctGamer That's what I'd expect if there's nobody on the pressure plate at the moment you look into the command block.

Comment: I was on the pressure plate